# Removing csv rows in Python

Tags: python, csv

A script is getting links from a csv file and scrapes some info from webpages. Some links don't work and the script fumbles. I've included a try/except, but this messes up my output, since I need the exact amount of output rows as in the original file.

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        url = row[4]
        req=urllib2.Request(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
    except:
        continue
```

Is there a way to delete the row from a csv file where there's a faulty link?
Something like:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        url = row[4]
        req=urllib2.Request(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
    except:
        continue
        DELETE_THE_ROW
```

Comment: Why do you ```"need the exact amount of output rows as in the original file"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible approach would be to create a new csv file and keep on writing only those rows whose links are valid.

```
f = open('another_csv.csv','w+')
for row in reader:
    try:
       url = row[4]
       req=urllib2.Request(url)
       tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
       print >>f,','.join(row)
    except:
       #can log the faulty links in another file
       continue
f.close()
```

You can rename the new csv to the original one, or keep both.

Comment: That works, but with some complications. Since there are commas in the original file (like in article headlines), the new file with ',' delimiter is super messed up. Is there a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Here you go : `print>>f, '"' + '","'.join(row) + '"'`

Comment: Or you could directly user csv.writer as mentioned in @Yann. It'll quote only those fields which have comma in them. Using quotations for all fields also increases the file size.

Answer (score 0):

If all goes well, why don't you write the good rows to another file?

```
writer = csv.writer(out_file_handle)
for row in reader:
    try:
        url = row[4]
        req=urllib2.Request(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
    except:
        continue
    else:
       writer.writerow(row)
```